# PRG Pattern problem?

Tags: php, redirect

I am using the [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern in my application. However, I have a problem:

In case I want to display a message at the GET stage, I can store it as as session variable at the POST stage (when it is decided what message should be displayed), for example `$_SESSION['message']='mplampla';`

Using this technique, the message should be unset after being displayed in order not to display it again erroneously in other pages. But if user the goes back and then forward to the GET page again, the message won't display the second time as it has been unset the first time around.

I don't know how other websites manage this... I have seen a web site with a registration form, which displays a message after successful registration under the same URL and works correctly when doing back/forward.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but if you unset the session then it wont show anymore because it doesn't exist...

Comment: unset after getting the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store the message in `$_SESSION`. Instead, pass it as a parameter to your GET page.

For example, in the GET stage, redirect the user to

`http://localhost/widget.php?edit=1&message=saved`

Then, in `widget.php` do:

```
$message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : null;
$output = null;
switch($message) {
    case 'completed': // possibly use a constant here, eg MESSAGE_COMPLETED
        $output = 'Your changes has been saved.';
        break;
    case 'failed':
        $output = 'ERROR: failed to save changes!';
        break;
}

// Now present $output to the user anyway you like
```

If the user goes back and forward, the message will still be displayed just fine. It also avoids any problems having to do with session state.

Comment: thank yoy for the suggestion.. However could you check how this works ?? https://secure.plaisio.gr/User/register.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Controls/Checkout/Default.aspx  it goes back and forward i dont know how when registered:S

Comment: Μην περιμένεις να κάνουμε και όλη τη δουλειά μόνοι μας... :)

Comment: Δε σου ζητησα να γραψεις κωδικα, αν εχεις ιδεα πως γινεται με το ιδιο url να βγαζει αλλο μηνυμα οπως κανουν στο πλαισιο!

Comment: That you can register and then although browser has the same url you can go back and forward and still display different pages and browser doesnt ask for posting again the data

Comment: That's not a page using the PRG pattern. Try hitting F5 after registering, you will see it's a POST request.

Comment: Yes i just found out that it isnt..However how they prevent browser from asking for reposting?

Comment: Install Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on your machine and have your browser use it as a proxy. Do the routine one more time and you will be able to see exactly what's going on in Fiddler.

Comment: ok..thank you... i did the same with Firebug and i think that the problem might be at cache control...